# C: CS50x - Week4 - Filter-more: 2D array size syntax

Tags: arrays, c, cs50

I cannot understand the syntax of the 2D array index. **(*Image)[width]**

Below is a part of the distribution C code of ProblemSet Filter-more, Week 3, cs50x. The code is not written by me, but by the cs50. I am self-learning through cs50 and trying to read and understand the script.

This is the way I understand this code: The 2nd paragraph defined a 2D array of RGBTRIPLE named *image* with the size of *[width]*. Each image[i] represents a vertical line of a picture.

However in the next few paragraphs the iterating condition of this array is *[i] < [height]*. And in the given comments, each image[i] works as a horizontal row.

And I couldn’t understand this part. I believe if [height] is a number bigger than [width], which is not stated in context, it would lead to a segmentation fault. For example: If height = 7, width = 4. The code defines image[4], then the below rows would tempt to iterate into image[5], image[6]…

Is this a bug in their code? Or it’s me who didn’t understand the syntax or the context correctly?

```
    // Get image's dimensions
    int height = abs(bi.biHeight);
    int width = bi.biWidth;

    // Allocate memory for image
    RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store image.\n");
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        return 7;
    }

    // Determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // Iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Read row into pixel array
        fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);

        // Skip over padding
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }
```

I asked ddb, the assistance ai of cs50, and he answered that this code could go wrong as I expected. But still I’m trying to make sure and looking forward to join a community discuss.
(I am not trying to be nitpicky. I am new to code learning, really grateful to cs50 curriculum and their willing to share. And I just couldn’t figure the correct answer on my own.)

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem, You get compilation error or runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

`image` is a *pointer* to an array (of `width` elements).

For this pointer you allocate `height` elements. That gives you an array of `height` elements, where each element is an array of `width` elements.

It is a dynamic way to create

```
RGBTRIPLE image[height][width];
```

This dynamic allocation is needed for larger image sizes, where a normal array would be too big to fit the space allocated for local variables.

Comment: Thank you. Still I wanna ask will the iteration (i=0; i< height; i++) image[i] lead to segmentation fault?

Comment: @Zim Since `i` will stay within the bounds allocated, there will not be any undefined behavior or crashes. At least not related to that.